# Как вставить изображение в таблицу в Jupyter Notebook

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, markdown

У меня есть отчёт с кодом в Jupyter Notebook, в котором я хочу привести таблицу с картинками. Этот отчёт я планирую сохранить в html и отправить.

**Вопрос:**

Как вставить картинки в таблицу так, чтобы ipynb экспортировался в html, корректно отображаемый на другом компьютере?

**Попытка решения №1**

Я попробовал создать таблицу через html в ячейке Markdown:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><img src="00.png"></td><td>Въезд запрещен</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="01.png"></td><td>Движение без остановки запрещено</td></tr>
</table>
```

После сохранения в hmtl и запуска из другой директории, картинки перестают отображаться (см. рис. 1), т.к. их нет в текущей директории. Я бы не хотел таскать кучу картинок вместе с html. Может быть можно вставить их в бинарном виде в html?

Рисунок 1.

[image: Изображения не отображаются]

**Попытка решения №2**

Я попробовал перетащить картинку курсором мыши в Google Chrome -- Jupyter сам сгенерировал Markdown:

```
![00.png](attachment:00.png)
```

Изображение вставленное такие образом корректно отображается после сохранения в hmtl из любой директории, однако если вставить изображения в таблицу следующим образом:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>![00.png](attachment:00.png)</td><td>Въезд запрещен</td></tr>
    <tr><td>![01.png](attachment:01.png)</td><td>Движение без остановки запрещено</td></tr>
</table>
```

то изображение перестаёт отображаться (см. рис. 2). В Markdown ошибка?

Рисунок 2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы создать таблицу с картинками в Jupyter нужно:

1. Выделить пустую ячейку.
2. Поменять тип ячейки с Code на Markdown (Cell -> Cell Type ->
   Markdown).
3. Написать таблицу (без картинок) на Markdown. Пример:

```
| Снимок | Название                         |
|--------|----------------------------------|
|        | Въезд запрещен                   |
|        | Движение без остановки запрещено |
```

4. Мышью перетащить картинки из файлового менеджера в браузер в ячейку Markdown. Должно получится:

```
| Снимок                       | Название                         |
|------------------------------|----------------------------------|
| ![00.png](attachment:00.png) | Въезд запрещен                   |
| ![01.png](attachment:01.png) | Движение без остановки запрещено |
```

5. Запустить код в ячейке Markdown (Ctrl+Enter). Должно получиться:

[image: Таблица с картинками]

6. Теперь можно сохранить получившийся ipynb в html (File -> Download as -> HTML).

Как ipynb, так и html можно переносить на другой компьютер без файлов картинок, и картинки там будут отображаться.

см. [Документация Markdown в Jupyter](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html).